# backbone.js / underscore.js error: has no method 'html'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I seem to be running into a brick wall with backbone.js / underscore.js when I try to import a template that looks like:

```
<script type="text/template" id="overview_template">
<div>
  Sample text
</div>
</script>
```

The error reads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html' navigation.js:356 
Backbone.View.extend.render navigation.js:356 
Backbone.View.extend.initialize navigation.js:351 
g.View backbone-min.js:33 d backbone-min.js:38 
(anonymous function) navigation.js:379 
f.Callbacks.n jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 
f.Callbacks.o.fireWith jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 
e.extend.ready jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2 c.addEventListener.B
```

The code that triggers the error is `this.el.html(template);` in the following:

```
 var OverviewView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $('#overview_container'),

  initialize: function() {
       this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    var template = _.template( $("#overview_template").html(), {} );
    this.el.html(template);
  },

  defaults: {
    tip_of_the_day: 'open',
    news: 'open',
    recent_presentations: 'open'
  },

  events: {
    "click .overview_subsection_header": "toggleSubsection"     
  },

  toggleSubsection: function (event) {
    $(this).parent().find('.overview_subsection_content').toggle();
  }
 });

 var overview_view = new OverviewView();
```

I'm not sure what is causing this but it's been driving me insane.

Answer (score 7):

.html() method is the method of jQuery object. When you use this.el - it's a DOM object. to get jQuery object use this.$el (it's cached by backbone.js jQuery object) or $(this.el).

So, your code should look like this:

```
  render: function() {
    var template = _.template( $("#overview_template").html(), {} );
    this.$el.html(template);    
  }
```

or

```
  render: function() {
    var template = _.template( $("#overview_template").html(), {} );
    $(this.el).html(template);    
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

shouldn't that be

`this.$el.html(template);`

ie. the jQuery wrapped el.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to connect the view to an existing element, `#overview_container`. But surely the view class is being created before the browser has initialised the DOM.

Since your template is stored at `#overview_container`, presumably you don’t want the view to be rendered in that element? Try removing the `el` property on the view and attaching the view’s element wherever you want it in the page.

Also, it’s a Backbone convention to return `this` from the `render` method so you can render and attach the element easily, something like this:

```
$(document.body).append((new OverviewView()).render().el);
```

You can `render` in the initialiser if you like, but it’s not standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
this.$el.html(template)
```

instead of

```
this.el.html(template)
```